# HashSet with Custom Type

Tags: java, hash, set

I would like to know why HashSet behaves strangely with custome type objects.In below code for String always it gives different results but for Human same type of result which is sorted.Is there something wrong in my

```
equals or hashCode or compareTo ?
```

Please hlep me to understand.Thanks in Advance.

**Bean :**

```
public class Human implements Comparable<Human>
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    // setters and getters
    public Human(int id,String name,int age)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }   

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {
        if(object != null && object instanceof Human)
        {
            if(this.id == ((Human)object).getId())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "id:"+this.id+":name:"+this.name+":age:"+age;
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Human human) {
        if(this.id > human.getId())
            return 1;
        else if(this.id < human.getId())
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
   }
```

**Code :**

```
System.out.println("HashSet");
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
set1.add("3");
set1.add("1");
set1.add("2");  
set1.add("4");

Iterator<String> iter1 = set1.iterator();
while(iter1.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(iter1.next());
}

System.out.println("HashSet with Custom Objects");

Set<Human> set11 = new HashSet<Human>();
set11.add(new Human(1, "joe", 26));
set11.add(new Human(3, "leo", 109));
set11.add(new Human(2, "king", 18));
set11.add(new Human(0, "vkgentle", 10));    

Iterator<Human> iter11 = set11.iterator();
while(iter11.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(iter11.next().toString());
}
```

**Output :**

```
HashSet
3
2
1
4
HashSet with Custom Objects
id:0:name:vkgentle:age:10
id:1:name:joe:age:26
id:2:name:king:age:18
id:3:name:leo:age:109
```

Comment: A `HashSet` is allowed to order things in any way it likes. That means they're allowed to be sorted, if the way it wants to order them happens to be sorted. That is just coincidence, though.

Comment: Try using humans with more random IDs (maybe 0, 1, 4000, 1234567, 14, 6743, 245) and they probably won't be sorted.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers and replys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing *broken*. The reason you're getting sorted results is because your custom hashCode method doesn't have a very random [hash distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hashing_uniformly_distributed_data).

The `HashSet` class is backed by an array of "buckets". When you add something to the `HashSet` it uses your `hashCode` method to figure out which bucket to use. I think it works something like this:

```
bucketIndex = object.hashCode() % arrayLength;
```

Since your `hashCode()` is just the ID, you end up with the Humans added to the buckets in order. If you mess with your hash function a bit in order to make it more randomly-distributed then you should get a more random ordering in the HashSet.

Comment: That hash function looks perfectly fine to me... In fact it's probably the same hash function as `Integer`. Are you suggesting `Integer.hashCode` is broken?

Comment: The problem with the hash function is that it might return the same hashcode for to object that aren't equals() and that may cause problem. While in the int case if the hashcode is the same they are also equals()

Comment: @immibis - You're right, it does match Integer's hash. I guess there really isn't a problem here as long as the hash function gives a good distribution in practice. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JonatanCloutier - The OP has also implemented `equals` in terms of `id`, so there's no issue there.

Comment: Well there is if you add to different object with the same id

Comment: @JonatanCloutier It works exactly as you would expect - you can't add equal objects. Saying that two things are equal iff they have the same ID might be unintuitive, but that is the programmer's problem and not `HashSet`'s problem, and it's not a problem with the hash function.

Comment: I agree but the question is "Is there something wrong in my equals or hashCode or compareTo" So the OP should be aware of this situation. As you say, it might be right

Answer (score 2):

> always it gives different results but for Human same type of result which is sorted.Is there something wrong in my

order in `HashSet` is not guaranteed, if you want ordered to be maintained respecting your `compareTo()` then use `TreeSet`

Answer (score 2):

The hashcode method of a string is a bit more complex that your simple return id;

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29

```
  s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

So that is why the order might seam strange on a string.

Now why is it ordered in the case of your custom object is because of the inner working of hashset. The important thing to remember is that : "It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time." But yet it still has to order them in some way to be able to find them fast. This order is based on the hashcode result modulo (%) the actual capacity of the hashset.

Your 3 method might be right for your need, but you should know that if two object are equals() and you add them both in your HashSet the second one will overwrite the first one. This is the your choice if the equality should be only on the id or on more field.